# ArcMap Maps Show in Layout View but Not Data View

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, display

I can see all my map layers in Layout view but get a blank white screen in Data View. Every help resource I searched seems to show thousands of questions and answers for the opposite problem.

I have tried zoom to layer and zoom to visible. I have tried setting display to wire frame and to always display. There are no red x's on any of the map layers and the source path's have not changed. These were all working fine yesterday.

This morning it was good, then I zoomed in and got a blank layer, zooming back out didn't return to the previous map. Pulling my hair out. Using military map deck made for CPOF, if that information is helpful to anyone.

Version 10.1
Problem exists on all saved and new mxds.
Problem exists at all scales.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What version of ArcGIS are you using?  Can you include a screenshot illustrating the problem?  Please [edit] your question to include any response to comments and additional information.

Comment: What is your scale set to?

Comment: Which data frame is active? Perhaps one with no data to display

Comment: I didn't know there were different data frames in data view. This sounds promissing. How do i change data frames in data view?

Comment: Have you tried zoom to layer?  It may just be focused on the wrong spot.

Comment: I have tried to zoom to layer and zoom to visible.

Comment: This persists in new mxds with the same data?

Comment: Activate data frame in layout view, switch to data view

Comment: GISKid, yes that is correct

Comment: @JoshuaCombs Can you [edit] your question and include a screenshot of your Table of Contents?  Try selecting a couple of features in one layer, and use Selection > Zoom to selected features

Comment: Can't do screen shots due to security constraints. I have tried zoom to layer and zoom to visible.

Comment: @JoshuaCombs have you tried zooming to selected feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a memory problem. Split up the personal geo databases and it works fine now.

I had one personal geodatabase with multiple Military Analyst catalogues in it. When I switched to just one MA catalogue in each file geodarabase it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted.  Could you [edit] your answer to expand on the problem and how you fixed it?  This could be useful for other users in the future if they run into the same problem.